# jquery ON event not firing in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I made this jsfiddle to demonstrate what I am meaning, but unfortunately JSfiddle itself doesn't seem to work with IE8 so you need to test this jsfiddle code in a stand alone page:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Bdbn/

With IE8 the above ON events does not fire, absolutely nothing happens. even adding an alert("hi") to the function does nothing; it doesn't get called, plus no errors are reporting in the console.

On a side note, is e.preventDefault() necessary to prevent a function being executed multiple times when you have multiple events triggering the same function, such as `.on("touchstart click",....`? In all situations?

jQuery version 1.8.3 so I believe IE8 is a supported browser.

ps. Im using IE10 in Browser Mode IE8.

EDIT: My simple test page which is not working in IE8 (for me):
http://www.personaltrainer.com.au/test.php

The relevant code section is...

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click touchstart",".something",function(e) {
        $(this).text($(this).text() + " "+e.type);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't downvote but the embedded result (http://jsfiddle.net/4Bdbn/embedded/result/) looks like it works for me on IE8 compat mode in IE10

Comment: Or at least the on click part works for me

Comment: @TomHeard thanks, appreciate that. Strange, yes it is working in that embed mode of jsfiddle. I wanted to test it in jsfiddle before posting here but couldnt get jsfiddle working in ie8 to test it, lol. nice to know this hack.  
anyway, strange that it doesn't work in IE8 on my simple test file that I copied into the fiddle.

Comment: Just a heads up. Simulating ie8 is not equivalent to actual ie8. I have had issues in past where if I run code in ie8 mode it would work but in actual ie8, it wont.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uGOYIhA/1/edit it also works in jsbin

Comment: Thanks @TomHeard - ive added a link to my own simple test page which doesn't work in my IE10 in IE8 browser mode.
Subash - thanks for pointing it out, I know I will need to do further testing in actual IE8 once I get to that stage. not looking forward to it.

Comment: @Martin In case you haven't seen these before, check out http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

Comment: Addition with my test page, in ie10 with ie8 Browser Mode, if I change the Document Mode to "Standards" Document Mode the test works, HOWEVER with the Document Mode as "IE8 Standards Mode (Page default)" it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an invalid `type` attribute (`application/javascript`) on your script tag. Change it to `text/javascript` or simply remove it all together.

This works just fine in IE8 (real version)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click touchstart",".something",function(e) {
        $(this).text($(this).text() + " "+e.type);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should remove the touchstart event first to check if it works! IE8 actually dosn't support touch action!

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on("click",".something", function(e) {
        $(this).text($(this).text() + " " + e.type);    
        //e.preventDefault();   
    });
});
```

Comment: Registering an event listener for *touchstart* doesn't stop IE8 from working

Comment: @Phil - That is what I thought. btw is it the same with jquery (mobile) tap event? if I had on("click tap",... would this throw errors on non mobile devices/browsers? (eg. if I didn't included the jquery mobile library on a non-mobile device and only included the library for mobile devices)? if that makes sense...

Comment: @Martin No idea, I've never used it. Try it and see :)